# Unexplained MySQL behavior using C libmysqlclient

Tags: mysql, c, key

I have written a processing engine in C that extracts 40k records from a table, processes the data and writes results to a different table. When I print out the processed data to the screen, it looks perfect so all of the variables are holding the right values. I need to write the data to a table that has 3 columns as the primary key. I create the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE halfcomp 
(
    MarketCode varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    TRZNum varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    origTRZNum varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (MarketCode, TRZNum, origTRZNum)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When the C program writes to the database, the results I get are trash. I get repeating values where I shouldn't, the results are out of order, the columns look switched in places, etc. I have been playing with this for a couple of days and I think that it has something to do with the primary key.

The reason I think this is because I made another table with an auto-incrementing integer primary key which freed my other values to just be plain old table values. I created the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE halfcomp
(
    Ind int(11) auto_increment NOT NULL,
    MarketCode varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    TRZNum varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    origTRZNum varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Ind)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I use the same C code to write to this table, the results are perfect. No repeating values, no mixed up columns. But here is the thing, I NEED the MarketCode, TRZNum, and origTRZNum columns to be the primary key. Am I creating my first table inappropriately? I am at a loss.

I have been over the C program with a fine tooth comb and it looks right, and the same C code works on other tables. But with this table, it does not work.  Any insight would be hugely appreciated! Thanks!

Edit: I have updated the code. I am no longer using malloc arbitrarily or sprintf, I am setting the buffer value directly to the value of my string variables. I tried adding a "\0" to the end of my strings as well. So far, nothing has helped, I am getting the same erratic behavior. This only happens when the values are primary keys, otherwise they load correctly. I have to assume that C adds a null terminator to the end of strings when it passes the database information to me in the beginning, and I use strcpy to pass the values back and forth when processing the data, so I have to believe that the null terminators are there already.  Any other thoughts??

```
int writeDB(void) {
    MYSQL *conn2;
    MYSQL_STMT *stmt2;
    MYSQL_BIND bind2[3];

    char *server = "localhost";
    char *user = "root";
    char *password = "";
    char *database = "thekeydb";
    int port = 3306;

    int k;
    int length = 15000;
    unsigned long mc2_length, mn2_length, om2_length;
    const char *insertStmt2 = "INSERT INTO tempcomp (MarketCode, TRZNum, origTRZNum) VALUES (?,?,?)";

    conn2 = mysql_init(NULL);
    mysql_real_connect(conn2, server,user,password,database, port, NULL, 0);
    stmt2 = mysql_stmt_init(conn2);
    mysql_autocommit(conn2, 0);
    mysql_query(conn2, "START TRANSACTION");

    for (k=0; k < length; k++) {
        memset((void *) bind2, 0, sizeof(bind2));

        mc2_length = strlen(comps[k].marketCode);
        mn2_length = strlen(comps[k].trzNum);
        om2_length = strlen(comps[k].origTrzNum);

        if (mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt2, insertStmt2, strlen(insertStmt2)) != 0) {
            printf("Unable to create new session: Could not prepare statement\n");
        }

        bind2[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
        bind2[0].buffer = comps[k].marketCode;
        bind2[0].buffer_length = STRING_SIZE;
        bind2[0].is_null = 0;
        bind2[0].length = &mc2_length;

        bind2[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
        bind2[1].buffer = comps[k].trzNum;
        bind2[1].buffer_length = STRING_SIZE;
        bind2[1].is_null = 0;
        bind2[1].length = &mn2_length;

        bind2[2].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
        bind2[2].buffer = comps[k].origTrzNum;
        bind2[2].buffer_length = STRING_SIZE;
        bind2[2].is_null = 0;
        bind2[2].length = &om2_length;

        if (mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt2, bind2) != 0) {
            printf("Unable to create new session: Could not bind parameters");
        }
        mysql_stmt_execute(stmt2);
        printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n", comps[k].marketCode, comps[k].trzNum, comps[k].origTrzNum, comps[k].address);
    }

    mysql_query(conn2, "COMMIT");
    mysql_autocommit(conn2, 1);
    mysql_stmt_free_result(stmt2);
    mysql_stmt_close(stmt2);
    mysql_close(conn2);

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost surely, you are not `null` terminating your strings. If you pass a string as a parameter to a prepared statement in *libmysqlclient* you MUST specify the length of the string. If your strings are not `null` terminated and you are using `strlen()` to pass the length to the `MYSQL_BIND` structure or, you are<sup>1</sup> passing them to `sprintf()` or similar to build the query, then an unexpected behavior like the behavior of your porgram is expected.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Don't do this if you are actually doing it, use prepared statements instead.</sub>

Comment: LOL I am using both strlen() and sprintf() to find lengths and pass parameters to the binding.  How can you be sure you are null terminating your strings?  I am new to C as well, so I don't know how to force my strings to be null terminated.

Comment: I added the code so you could see how I was passing the strings.  I get the data to do all this from a call to the database.  I populate a 2D array(a structure of structures) to hold all of the data.  Refering to this global array is how I pass the string to the binding.  Do I need to concatenate something to the end of my strings somehow?

Comment: I have tried to use strcat() to add "\0" to the end of my strings before using functions like sprintf and strlen, but I am still getting the same erratic behavior.  When I executed the query to get all of my data at the beginning, I fetch each row and then pass the row data to my variables.  I would think that if they were strings, they would have been passed by the API with null values already included in the strings, wouldn't you?  I really want to believe that your null-termination theory is correct, but I am not convinced.  I must still be doing something wrong.

Comment: You don't need to `sprintf()` anything, and also you apparently `malloc()` an arbitrary size, you should `malloc()` an exact size.

Comment: True. I am using an arbitrary size for malloc(). I will change that. Two questions (1) Do I need to add a terminating null to my strings or should I assume they are already there? (2) For the buffer_length when binding, I am using an arbitrary value of 50 to accommodate the length of all of the strings passed to the database. Does it need to be an exact value?

Comment: I have tried null-terminating my strings.  I have taken out malloc and sprintf altogether and just set the buffer value directly to my variable values.  Nothing is helping.  From what I have read last night, null terminated strings would seem the most likely candidate.  But why does it write perfectly if they are not in the Primary Key of the database?  Why have I been able to write other tables using the same exact code with no errors.  If it was string problems, it surely would have shown up in other scenarios.  Any other thoughts???

Comment: It is highly unlikely that it has to do with whether or not the columns are primary keys. It's undefined behavior what you're experiencing. Primary key or not, a column is a column.

Comment: I edited my code if you can take a look at it.  It certainly is undefined behavior, the question is, is it related to strings? I get the initial info from the database, which I have to assume that C adds a null terminator when it obtains the strings.  I use strcpy to pass the data back and forth when doing the processing.  I print the data to the screen before I write to the database, and it all looks correct.  The only problem is when I write to the database.  The only other arbitrary thing i use is STRING_SIZE for the buffer_length, which i set to 50 to accommodate all strings.  Is that OK?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of the community, I must answer this problem honestly, though I admit that I am very embarassed to do so.  At this point, I believe that I was writing the data to the database correctly the whole time, but viewing the database data incorrectly for comparison.  When I was printing the data to the screen, I was looking at three columns.  The first was a totally repeating market code, the second was a fairly random code, and the third was a code that would repeat in groups of 5 or 8 or whatever.  When I would do a "SELECT * FROM tempcomp" to view the data, it was the 2nd column that would repeat but in smaller groups like 2 or 3, and the third column looked random.  I now believe that MySQL Workbench was sorting the data somehow before it presented it to me.  Thus the database display was different from what the program was displaying.  When I would use an auto_incrementing integer as a primary key, the database displayed the data in the same order as the screen display.  But it sorted the output differently when my three columns were the primary key. It has been a miserable 3 days trying to figure this out, and to find out that there is actually no error in my code is embarassing to say the least.